# How to use Prime NG messageService in global HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-http-interceptors

I am currently trying to implement a global error handler in my application using PrimeNG 9 messageService and Angular 8 HttpInterceptor. My code is the following:

**app.component.html**

```
//....

<p-toast key="notification" position="top-right"></p-toast>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [ ...
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
        multi: true,
      },
 ...
```

**errror-interceptor.interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ɵConsole } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  public intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (httpRequest.method !== 'GET')
      return next.handle(httpRequest);
    else {
      return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
        catchError( (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err)
          this.messageService.add({
            key: 'notification',
            severity: 'error',
            summary: 'Woops! There was an error!',
          });
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
    }

  }
```

The interceptor successfully catches errors and prints them in the console. However, the toast is never displayed. I also point out that i make use of messageService in other components and the toasts are correctly displayed, it just does not work in the interceptor.

Comment: can you add a stackblitz please ... I have same thing in my add and it works correctly

Comment: @bubbles are you using HttpInterceptor and PrimeNG messageService?

Comment: @bubbles is your application on GitHub or on other open source folders? I'd like to take a look at the code to check what is wrongly configured in mine!

Comment: you can add your code here https://stackblitz.com/ and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

had u declare and call for the toaster at desire location?
eg. at x-page.module, u need to declare where the toaster/function/whatever is and in x-page.ts calling it

Comment: I don't understand the answer, can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

add to "deps" array in app.module

```
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AuthService, MessageService],
    }
```